# table-layout:fixed not expanding table-cells inside absolute 100% width table-row (elements not collapsing either)

Tags: css, css-position, tablelayout, css-tables, dynamic-pages

This makes no sense to me, but then again, I'm not anywhere close to a CSS expert (probably not even a good novice).

I'm using `relative`/`absolute` because I'm using dynamically paginated tables from huge tables.  I do this to allow the user to rapidly thumb through data without overloading the client.

[As you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/qfNML/1/), the `table-row` expands 100%, but the `table-cell`s don't obey `table-layout:fixed`.  Need the `table-cell`s to expand to fill all available `table-row` space.

(Side note, the `border-collapse: collapse` doesn't work either.)

Please help.  Many thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<div class="gridTable">
    <div class="gridRow">
        <div class="gridCell">a</div>
        <div class="gridCell">JKL;</div>    
        <div class="gridCell">Jb</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gridTable{
display:table;
table-layout:fixed;
position:relative;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.gridHeaderRow{
top:0px;
}
.gridRow, .gridHeaderRow{
display:table-row;
position:absolute;
}
.gridCell{
display:table-cell;
}
.gridTable, .gridRow, .gridHeaderRow{
width:100%;
}
.gridTable, .gridTable *{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
.gridTable div{
border-color:black;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the position absolute from the row rule and it worked for me (chrome, firefox)

```
.gridRow, .gridHeaderRow{
  display:table-row;
}
```

In case you want to have a fixed header, you could separate the header like this:

```
<div class="gridTableBox">
    <div class="gridTable gridHeaderTable">
        <div class="gridRow">
            <div class="gridCell">T1</div>
            <div class="gridCell">T2</div>
            <div class="gridCell">T3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridTable gridBody">
        <div class="gridRow">
            <div class="gridCell">a</div>
            <div class="gridCell">JKL;</div>
            <div class="gridCell">Jb</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can giv the gridHeaderTable div a absolute positiion without breaking the table-layout.

Updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7SJ4V/1/).

Comment: Maybe you could separate the "header" and "body" like in that updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7SJ4V/1/